# Show that $\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\cos(n)+n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}=\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \tfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\cos(n)+n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) $$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side

My Proof:

> Note that :
>   $$\left(1+x\right)^{\alpha}=1+\mathcal{O}\left( x\right) \quad x \to 0$$
>   $$\left|\left(\dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}  \right)\right|\leq \left(\dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}  \right) \underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\longrightarrow }0 $$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\cos(n)+n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}\left(1+\dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}} \right)^{-1} \\
&= \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}  \right) \right)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{\tfrac{3}{4}}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) 
\end{align*}

since 
$$\left|\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) }{\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) }\right| \leq 1 \implies \mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) =\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) $$

- Is my proof correct

Comment: It's seems OK to me.

Comment: but i got $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\cos(n)}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) $ not $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{\tfrac{3}{2}}}\right) $

Comment: It's fine since $|\cos(n)|\le1$.